# Sphere covering by quadrilaterals

Tags: general-topology, geometry

If we question is badly stated - please suggest a better wording.

I have the following problem: Given a sphere, I want to split it into a number of non-overlapping "quadrilateral" areas, such that each area has exactly $4$ neighbors.

So, I have come with a pretty generic way that splits the sphere into $k \cdot n$ such areas, where $k \geq 2$ and $n \geq 3$. In the image the central belt is optional and you take $k-2$ such belts, while upper and lower parts are there. $n$ is the number of "quadrilateral" pieces in each "belt".

> The question is: Is it possible to split a sphere into $p$ such areas,
> there $p \geq 7$ - is prime?

For $p=5$ direct calculations of Euler characteristic helps, as there are $5$ faces, $10$ different edges, and each vertex - is adjacent to at least $3$ faces. We have $20$ (possibly duplicate) vertices - which gives us at most $6$ vertices. Plugging into the $F - E + V$ gives us at most $1$, while it should be $2$ [since we are on the sphere].

[image: systematic sphere covering]

Comment: Does it need to be convex? If not you can just split the two poles with $n$ longitudes and then deform each longitude a little bit in the middle so it forms two line segments.

Comment: Actually for every $n\geq 6$ you can just start with a cube, subdivide each face of the cube so that the total number is equal to $n$, and then deform the cube into a sphere. Every quarilateral is guaranteed to be convex as well.

Comment: @cr001, Actually, this is the underlying question, and cubes have an even number of quadrilaterals.

Comment: You can split one square into three rectangles by drawing two vertical lines.

Comment: A cube can have any number of rectangles.

Comment: @cr001, you actually can't, cause it creates too many neighbors for the previous neighbors of that same square

Comment: You are right. The cube method doeesn`t work.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a method to tile the sphere with $p \geq 11$ - a prime number of quadrilaterals.

[image: sphere covering by an odd number of tiles]

In the above image, i have taken a $k$-teeth upper half with a $k+2$-teeth lower counterpart and pushed a $3$ -quadrilateral piece.

This systematic solution is good for any odd number of quadrilaterals for tiling, where number of tiles is above $10$.

I'm still missing an answer for $p = 7$.